# Constant Contact API, Adding a new contact in python

Tags: python, constantcontact

I'm completely new at this, and a bit in over my head. I've been writing a program to import contacts into Constant Contact using their API. I've got most of it down, and seemingly only one more stumbling block... I've got a `403 Forbidden error` popping up. I'm hoping it's just my formatting , and that one of you fine folks can point out where I've screwed up.

Here's my python code:

```
url2 = 'https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts' + '?action_by=ACTION_BY_VISITOR&api_key=foonumber'

headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer barnumber', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
data2 = json.dumps({"lists": [{"id": "1313956673"}],"email_addresses": [{"email_address": "test@example.com"}]})
req = urllib2.Request(url2, data2, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

So something's wrong here, because the return I get on my `response = urllib.urlopen(req)` line is a `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

I've double checked the api key and the access token, and they both work for the GET request earlier in the program.

Answer (score 0):

I have used various Constant Contact APIs (v1 & v2) and the kind your error you are having usually means you are trying to access content that is restricted or not available to you. Passing the right api_key and access token is not a guarantee it will work.

So make sure any kind of data you are passing currently exists in your account (listid). Also try removing that `action_by=ACTION_BY_VISITOR`you have in your URL just to make sure it's not causing any issue, if not you can always add it back later.

This is not necessary but I've found out it sometimes work wonders, try adding an X-Originating-Ip header to your request.